# How to declare a two-dimensional array by one cell formula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

In Excel it is pretty simple, for example
`={1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8}` gives us 2 rows in 4 columns.
But when I try similar in Google Spreadsheet, it fails.

EDIT: See comments below where the language version issue was revealed.

Comment: Add the textual error message.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly the same syntax, but different entry methods:

## Excel

Hi-light a **block** of cells and array enter:

```
={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

## Google Sheets

Select a **single** cell and enter:

```
={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

and the extension to the other cells occurs automatically:

[image]

Same is true for *2-D* arrays:

[image]

If you are using Google Sheets, **remember to leave enough empty cells to the right and below to hold the result.**

Comment: Please tell me why I get error after entering such formula?
That was what I initially thought about but I've got the error and then asked a question.
https://i.imgur.com/DMzbgwi.png

Comment: @friedman  I looked at your snapshot and cannot explain the error. **leave this question open so someone else can help us.**

Comment: Is it possible that it's a language version issue? I just shot different characters as separators and after entering `={1\2\3\4;5\6\7\8}` I got the right effect. I use polish version but wonder how this formula will work when someone opens it on english?

Comment: @friedman First **good Job!** uncovering the problem.  Second I don't know enough about Google Sheets to be able to make it *"international"* (if that is the correct term)

Comment: Maybe you'd check if you have an error after entering my formula?

Comment: @friedman I tried your formula and it produced and error in my system.

Comment: @friedman  **don't give up** perhaps someone else can help us.

Comment: just share the spreadsheet's copy so that people can try to figure out why you are getting this error

Comment: @friedman's backslashes saved the day for me. Also for some reason both on excel and on google sheets the default separator for me for the commands is ;